# Convert crypto.randomBytes() to 8 digit random integer

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, cryptojs

In my node.js server side code, while trying to create 8 digit random number, the result is not as expected.

I tried below code,

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
var token = crypto.randomBytes(8);

console.log(token);
```

Still it returns bufferred bytearray which is `<Buffer 1d c3 02 b1 d1 0b e9 dc>`.
Tried a lot of methods to convert that byte array to 8 digit number like 98988348(Not a hexadecimal one).

But still not able to get the 8 Digit random number.

Note:Don't want to use `Math.random()` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### crypto.randomInt (Node.js v14.10+/v12.19+)

As of Node.js v14.10 (and v12.19), the [`crypto` module](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) exports a [`randomInt([min], max, [callback])`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randomint_min_max_callback) function which returns a random integer `n` such that `min <= n < max`. This function inherits all of the security benefits that the `crypto` module as a whole provides.

So to get a random 8 digit integer, you'd be looking to invoke the `randomInt` function with a min value of `10000000` and a max of `100000000`:

```js
const { randomInt } = require('crypto');

const n = randomInt(10000000, 100000000);
```

### crypto.randomBytes

An alternative that doesn't have strict Node.js version requirements would be to convert your buffer to a hex string, and then use the `parseInt` function specifying the `base` parameter as 16 (for hex).

You can then divide that parsed integer by the largest possible value (`0xffffffffffffffff`) to get a cryptographically-secure number between 0 and 1.

Now you just need to multiply this by `(max - min)` (90000000 in your case) and then add the `min` (10000000).

```js
const { randomBytes } = require('crypto');

const token = crypto.randomBytes(8);
const hex = token.toString('hex');

const min = 10000000;
const max = 100000000;

let n = parseInt(hex, 16); // 0   <= n < 2^64
n /= 0xffffffffffffffff;   // 0   <= n < 1
n *= max - min;            // 0   <= n < max - min
n += min;                  // min <= n < max
```

Comment: Thanks Luke, May I know is there is any other solutions for older versions of node?

Comment: Please see my edited answer with an alternative that just uses randomBytes.

Comment: But it will output it as decimal number like 0.4184526527047584. But I need only 8digit random whole number

Comment: I was trying to leave that for you to figure out on your own :) You need to multiply the number by (max - min) and then add the min (your min is 10000000 and your max is 100000000). See my edit.